Bounty for invalid question?
What should I do after setting bounty for a kind of invalid question, and answers are useful but not actually solving the problem specified in the question?
Can I use single address for all my transactions?

To be honest, I'm not really sure what you're asking. Have you tried clarifying your question?

Yes. My motivation is to keep my firstbits address to receive Bitcoin always. Any solution would fine with me, but that question only explores possibility with scripts.
